Parsing Nested JSON without headers into SQL Database
I have a nested JSON without headers and I want to parse it using SQL into a SQL table.
Here's the sample of the data:
[
    [ 123, 1123, "94.05", 
      [ 
        [ 11234, 31040, "100.00",
          [ 
            [ 112345, 252783, 20, "Pass", "YES"],       
            [ 61169237, 252785, 5, "Pass", "YES" ],
            [ 61169238, 252788, 5, "Pass", "YES" ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
]

Here's my query. I'm able to parse the first part of the JSON, but not the nested ones. How do I reference the nested JSONs since they don't have headers.
SELECT 
    m.[udAuditID], m.[assessmentID],
    m.category_json,
    s.CatID, s.CategoryID,
    s.Score, s.SecID, s.SectionID
FROM 
    [dbo].auditfinal m
CROSS APPLY 
    OPENJSON(m.category_json) 
        WITH (
             CatID BIGINT '$[0]',
             CategoryID BIGINT '$[1]',
             Score VARCHAR(max)'$[2]',
             SecID BIGINT '$[0][0]',
             SectionID BIGINT '$[0][1]'
             ) s

As you can see in the results below, I'm able to parse the first set shown in yellow, but not beyond that.

Any help or suggestion you can give is appreciated!

If your JSON contains nested blocks / arrays, you can keep adding further APPLY subqueries until you get to the very bottom of it.
If your JSON schema is static, you can probably construct a fixed query that will give you everything you're after. Something along these lines:
-- Your example JSON value
declare @v nvarchar(max) = N'[
    [
        123,
        1123,
        "94.05",
        [
            [
                11234,
                31040,
                "100.00",
                [
                    [ 112345, 252783, 20, "Pass", "YES" ],
                    [ 61169237, 252785, 5, "Pass", "YES" ],
                    [ 61169238, 252788, 5, "Pass", "YES" ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]';

select *
from openjson(@v, '$[0]') r
    outer apply (
        select a.[key] as [Key2], a.value as [V2], a.type as [Type2]
        from openjson(r.value, '$[0]') a
        where r.type = 4
    ) l1
    outer apply (
        select a.[key] as [Ordinal],
            json_value(a.value, '$[0]') as [Val1],
            json_value(a.value, '$[1]') as [Val2],
            json_value(a.value, '$[2]') as [Val3],
            json_value(a.value, '$[3]') as [Val4],
            json_value(a.value, '$[4]') as [Val5]
        from openjson(l1.V2, '$') a
        where l1.Type2 = 4
    ) l2;

In order to avoid issues when OPENJSON tries to parse a non-JSON value, each of these nested subqueries have type = 4 filters, so that only JSON objects will be attempted, and not scalar values.
If your JSON structure is dynamic and unpredictable, you will need some kind of a generalised hierarchical parser. The example below can be used as a starting point. Just don't expect it to be fast.
-- Based on the same variable as above
with cte as (
    select cast(r.[key] as varchar(max)) as [AxisPath], r.value as [Value],
        r.type as [ValueType]
    from openjson(@v, '$') r
    union all
    select c.AxisPath + '.' + cast(d.[key] as varchar(max)), d.value,
        d.type
    from cte c
        cross apply openjson(c.Value, '$') d
    where c.ValueType = 4 -- JSON objects only
)
select *
from cte c
-- Should be no JSON left unparsed in the end
where c.ValueType != 4
order by c.AxisPath;


Thanks! I think the first part may work for me, but how do I make those values appear in separate columns since that is how I want to store the values in the table.

@LakshmiHariharan, I don't follow. They are already in separate columns, aren't they?

Hi, what I mean is the actual values in the Json are shown as rows in the resultset and I want them in separate columns, to put them in a SQL table. I want them flattened. Is that possible to do?

@LakshmiHariharan, you mean the values from the innermost array, [ 112345, 252783, 20, "Pass", "YES" ] - these? Well, you can use pivot, or you can add a separate apply for each array element and modify its openjson() by adding element ordinals: from openjson(l2.V3, '$[0]') c. Only, this will work if the array always has exactly 3 elements. I wouldn't rely on that.

Disregard the previous comment. I've updated the query in the answer.
